# Python Cubes OLAP Framework - how to work with joins?

Tags: python, database, olap, star-schema

I'm trying to use python's olap framework [cubes](http://packages.python.org/cubes/) on a very simple database, but I am having some trouble joining tables.

My schema looks like this:

```
Users table
ID | name

Products table
ID | name | price

Purchases table
ID | user_id | product_id | date
```

And the cubes model:

```
{
    'dimensions': [
        {'name': 'user_id'},
        {'name': 'product_id'},
        {'name': 'date'},
    ],
    'cubes': [
        {
            'name': 'purchases',
            'dimensions': ['user_id', 'product_id', 'date'],
            'measures': ['price']
            'mappings': {
                'purchases.user_id': 'users.id',
                'purchases.product_id': 'products.id',
                'purchases.price': 'products.price'
            },
            'joins': [
                {
                    'master': 'purchases.user_id',
                    'detail': 'users.id'
                },
                {
                    'master': 'purchases.product_id',
                    'detail': 'products.id'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I would like to display all the purchases, showing the product's name, user's name and purchase date. I can't seem to find a way to do this. The documentation is a bit scarce.

Thank you

Comment: OLAP is not designed to do joins.  Use an SQL database instead, maybe.

Comment: @AaronWatters Python's Cubes framework provides this functionality. It is a MySQL backend.

Comment: To clarify: joins are hidden from the end user, they are part of logical-to-physical mapping and specified in the logical model.Also Cubes has many relational database backends, not only MySQL - all backends that are supported by SQLAlchemy. That includes: PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLite and many more.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First let's fix the model a bit. In your schema you have more attributes per dimension: id and name, you might end up having more details in the future. You can add them by specifying attributes as a list: `"attriubtes": ["id", "name"]`. Note also that the dimension is named as entity `product` not as a key `id_product`. The key `id_product` is just an attribute of the `product` dimension, as is `name` or in the future maybe `category`. Dimension reflects analysts point of view.

For the time being, we ignore the fact that date should be a special dimension and consider date as single-value key, for example a year, not to make things complicated here.

```js
"dimensions": [
    {"name": "user", "attributes": ["id", "name"]},
    {"name": "product", "attributes": ["id", "name"]},
    {"name": "date"}
],
```

Because we changed names of the dimensions, we have to change them in the cube's dimension list:

```js
"cubes": [
    {
        "name": "purchases",
        "dimensions": ["user", "product", "date"],
        ...
```

Your schema reflects classic transactional schema, not traditional data warehouse schema. In this case, you have to be explicit, as you were, and mention all necessary mappings. The rule is: if the attribute belongs to a fact table (logical view), then the key is just `attribute`, such as `price`, no table specification. If the attribute belongs to a dimension, such as `product.id`, then the syntax is `dimension.attribute`. The value of the mappings dictionary is physical table and physical column. See [more information about mappings](http://packages.python.org/cubes/mapping.html#mapping). Mappings for your schema look like:

```js
"mappings": {
    "price": "products.price",
    "product.id": "products.id",
    "product.name": "products.name",
    "user.id": "users.id",
    "user.name": "users.name"
}
```

You would not have to write mappings if your schema was:

```
fact purchases
id | date | user_id | product_id | amount

dimension product
id | name | price

dimension user
id | name
```

In this case you will need only joins, because all dimension attributes are in their respective dimension tables. Note the `amount` in the fact table, which in your case, as you do not have `count` of purchased products per purchase, would be the same as `price` in `product`.

Here is the updated model for your model:

```js
{
    "dimensions": [
        {"name": "user", "attributes": ["id", "name"]},
        {"name": "product", "attributes": ["id", "name"]},
        {"name": "date"}
    ],
    "cubes": [
        {
            "name": "purchases",
            "dimensions": ["user", "product", "date"],
            "measures": ["price"],
            "mappings": {
                "price": "products.price",
                "product.id": "products.id",
                "product.name": "products.name",
                "user.id": "users.id",
                "user.name": "users.name"
            },
            "joins": [
                {
                    "master": "purchases.user_id",
                    "detail": "users.id"
                },
                {
                    "master": "purchases.product_id",
                    "detail": "products.id"
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

You can try the model without writing any Python code, just by using the [`slicer`](http://packages.python.org/cubes/slicer.html) command. For that you will need `slicer.ini` [configuration file](http://packages.python.org/cubes/server.html#configuration):

```
[server]
backend: sql
port: 5000
log_level: info
prettyprint: yes

[workspace]
url: sqlite:///data.sqlite

[model]
path: model.json
```

Change `url` in `[workspace]` to point to your database and change `path` in `[model]` to point to your model file. Now you can try:

```
curl "http://localhost:5000/aggregate"
```

Also try to drill-down:

```
curl "http://localhost:5000/aggregate?drilldown=product"
```

If you need any further help, just let me know, I'm the Cubes author.

Comment: "For the time being, we ignore the fact that date should be a special dimension"
If one would want to know more about that, and one is using an SQL data store: the trick for parsing a date down to its fields is explained at https://pythonhosted.org/cubes/backends/sql.html#date-data-type

Comment: Do the field names "id" and "name" have special meanings?

Comment: The link `https://pythonhosted.org/cubes/mapping.html` on "more information about mappings" returns 404.

Comment: Perhaps it meant to link to this? https://pythonhosted.org/cubes/schemas.html#mappings